# Calculating output of an electric heater under different voltage

Tags: homework-and-exercises

I'm working through some electric theory problems, and I stumbled on one I am certain I'm overthinking:

> A $120\,\rm V$, $100\,\rm W$ bulb is connected to $208\,\rm V$. What is the output of the bulb?

I know that I can calculate a current value by doing $P =E \times I$. Where I am confused is that after I have this current value, do I simply substitute it in to the new formula?

$P = E \times I \quad \Rightarrow \quad 100\,\mathrm{W} = 120 \times I \quad \Rightarrow \quad I = 0.8333\,\rm A$

Then $P = E \times I \quad \Rightarrow \quad P = 208 \times 0.8333$

More specifically, why would the current of this lightbulb remain the same when a new voltage is applied?

Comment: If the question is related to a practical purpose, it is not reasonable to assume the resistance of the bulb remains constant. As the power increases the temperature of the filament will increase and so will the resistance. So the power output will be lower than the estimate for constant resistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may assume the resistance of the bulb remains constant (which is reasonable under most operational temperatures). So

$$E^2 / R = 100\,\rm W$$

$$
\begin{align}
&\Rightarrow &\quad \frac{(120\,\mathrm{V})^2}{R} &= 100\,\rm W\\
&\Rightarrow &\quad R &= \frac{14400\,\mathrm{V^2}}{100\,\rm W}\\
&&&= 144\,\Omega
\end{align}
$$

So, the new output (power) for $208\,\rm V$ is

$$P = \frac{(208\,\mathrm{V})^2}{144\,\Omega} = 300.44\,\rm W$$

The current won't remain the same.

I could be wrong, it's been 10 years I touched anything in physics.